# ES6: Why am I getting null when matching on my regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ecmascript-6

I have a regex in a variable

The purpose of my regex is to list down all of allowable characters for user input

Note that the regex may change from time to time depending on the user preference

```
var regex = new RegExp(passParamStateMap.value, "g");
```

The value of my regex after console.log is

```
/~@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;<>,.?\//g
```

However, when I try to match it with user input, I am getting `null` value

Can someone enlighten me please.

```
var regex = new RegExp(passParamStateMap.value, "g");

     if( e.target.value.match(regex) ){ //null value
       passError.concat("allowable")
     }
```

Sample use case:

1. User edits in password parameter maintenance module the field `Allowable Special Characters`
2. User defined these as allowable: `~@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;<>,.?`
3. Now, on my `New Password` field, the only allowable special characters are the ff: `~@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;<>,.?`
4. Can I achieve this requirement using regex? Note that the value `~@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;<>,.?` may change

Comment: What input value are you testing? That's a very specific regex, are those characters meant to be within a [character-class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) perhaps?

Comment: This regexp is kind of invalid. First you want the string to end with `#` but also contain `%` after the ending - which kind of defeats the definition of end of string. Then after the string ends you want it to start with `&` but how can a string start after it ends?

Comment: Sorry this regex is meant to be a list of allowable characters. I get this from a JSON response

Comment: For us to help you, you have to do TWO things.  1) Define what the objective is for your regex in words. 2) Show us one or  more sample inputs that you think should match and define what they should match.  Right now you have a regex that would only match a very  bizarre sequence of special characters.  It seems unlikely that's what you want.  So, you need to describe WHAT you want this to do and then we can help you   better.

Comment: I see. Sorry I didn't know what some of these sequence may look very bizarre in regex. Will edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a charset for the characters in your regex:

```
/[~@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;<>,.?\/]/g
```

This will match any of the characters - and you can make it work with your current code like this:

```
new RegExp("[" + passParamStateMap.value + "]", "g");
```

Note that when you parse `passParamStateMap.value`, you may need to escape the special characters like `[` and `]`, as the `]` will end the character class prematurely. Here's a function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/10221765) that'll let you do just that:

```
new RegExp("[" + passParamStateMap.value.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "]", "g");
```

Comment: May need to escape the `]` otherwise the character class close too early

Comment: Tried the code above and when I use console.log it outputs `/[~@#$%^&*()_+{}[]:;<>,.?\/]/g` however, when I compare to `e.target.value` I still get `null` value

Comment: Apply the sanitisation code at the bottom @iamjpcbau

Comment: Thanks! I think its working now. But I have a question, what if the regex suddenly changes. Since my regex is from a variable, its very dynamic. e.g. user removed `@` and `#` it became `/[~$%^&*()_+{}[]:;<>,.?\/]/g` what changes should I do to make the regex adapt? Sorry for my english

Comment: The code at the bottom (`new RegExp("[" + passParamStateMap.value.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + "]", "g");`) will dynamically take the value in `passParamStateMap.value`, sanitise it, and make a global regex matching any character from it - so this will solve your problem, just put the string in `passParamStateMap.value`, or pass the value into a function.